Testcontainers: Azure pipeline test stage reach timeout of 1hour
I'm using .NET 8 within xUNit and TestContainers for my integration testing.
i'm using a fixture for my 3 test files means that 3 docker containers are created for every classFixture.
Example
namespace API.Tests.Queries;

using Infrastructure.Reporting.Abstracts;
using Tests.Fixtures;
using Application.Configuration;
using Tests.Helpers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NSubstitute;
using Testcontainers.MsSql;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using MediatR;
using FluentAssertions;

public class GenerateTests(Fixture fixture) : IClassFixture<GenerateTests.Fixture>
{
    private readonly Fixture fixture = fixture;

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Plumieux", "FR", GenerationMode.RULE)]
    [InlineData("Abc", "BE", GenerationMode.RULE)]
    public async Task GivenFarmNameAndCountryCode_Generate_FromRules_Succeful(string farmName, string countryCode, GenerationMode generationMode)
    {
        // Arrange
        var mediator = fixture.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

        // Act
        var result = await mediator.Send(new GenerateQuery
        {
            FarmName = farmName,
            CountryCode = countryCode
        });

        // Assert
        result.Should().NotBeNull();
        result.GenerationMode.Should().Be(generationMode);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("BAZ", "FR", GenerationMode.RANDOM_FARM_NAME_BASED)]
    public async Task GivenFarmNameAndCountryCode_Generate_RandomMode_Succeful(string farmName, string countryCode, GenerationMode generationMode)
    {
        // Arrange
        var mediator = fixture.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

        // Act
        var result = await mediator.Send(new GenerateQuery
        {
            FarmName = farmName,
            CountryCode = countryCode
        });

        // Assert
        result.Should().NotBeNull();
        result.Pentagram.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        result.GenerationMode.Should().Be(generationMode);
    }
    public class Fixture : ServiceProviderFixture, IAsyncLifetime
    {
        private MsSqlContainer MsSqlContainer { get; } = new MsSqlBuilder().Build();
        private bool IsContainerUpAndRunning { get; set; }
        private bool IsContainerDisposed { get; set; }

        public Fixture()
        {
            var configuration = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
            Services
                .AddApplicationServices()
                .AddSingleton(configuration)
                .AddSingleton(MsSqlContainer)
                .AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(NullLogger<>))
                .AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory, TestsDbConnectionFactory>();
        }
        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            if (!IsContainerUpAndRunning)
            {
                await MsSqlContainer.StartAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Container {MsSqlContainer.Name}  {MsSqlContainer.Id}: Started");
                await using var connection = new SqlConnection(MsSqlContainer.GetConnectionString());
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                await ExecuteSeedingScript(connection, "script1.sql");
                await ExecuteSeedingScript(connection, "script2.sql");
                await connection.CloseAsync();
                IsContainerUpAndRunning = true;
            }
        }

        public Task DisposeAsync()
        {
            if (IsContainerDisposed)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            IsContainerDisposed = true;
            return MsSqlContainer.DisposeAsync().AsTask();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute Seeding files
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connection"></param>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task ExecuteSeedingScript(SqlConnection connection, string filename)
        {
            var currentDirectory = FileHelper.GetPathToCurrentTestProject();
            var sqlSeedingScript = await File.ReadAllTextAsync($"{currentDirectory}/Database/{filename}");
            await using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSeedingScript, connection);
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}


when i'm running this locally it works perfect.
But it appear that it's randomly failing on the azure pipeline.
it take 1h when trying to delete the container, and the pipeline fail with timeout error.
Starting: Run tests
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.242.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/usr/bin/dotnet test /home/vsts/work/1/s/Tests/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Architecture.Tests/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Architecture.Tests.csproj --configuration Release --no-build
Test run for /home/vsts/work/1/s/Tests/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Architecture.Tests/bin/Release/net8.0/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Architecture.Tests.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.10.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    12, Skipped:     0, Total:    12, Duration: 239 ms - Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Architecture.Tests.dll (net8.0)
/usr/bin/dotnet test /home/vsts/work/1/s/Tests/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Tests/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Tests.csproj --configuration Release --no-build
Test run for /home/vsts/work/1/s/Tests/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Tests/bin/Release/net8.0/Darwin.AssetManagement.PlantConnection.API.Tests.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.10.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[testcontainers.org 00:00:00.26] Connected to Docker:
  Host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  Server Version: 26.1.3
  Kernel Version: 6.5.0-1023-azure
  API Version: 1.45
  Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
  Total Memory: 6.76 GB
[testcontainers.org 00:00:00.40] Searching Docker registry credential in Auths
[testcontainers.org 00:00:00.41] Docker registry credential https://index.docker.io/v1/ found
[testcontainers.org 00:00:00.82] Searching Docker registry credential in CredHelpers
[testcontainers.org 00:00:00.82] Searching Docker registry credential in CredsStore
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.22] Docker image testcontainers/ryuk:0.6.0 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.30] Docker container 0f4546652020 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.35] Start Docker container 0f4546652020
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.86] Wait for Docker container 0f4546652020 to complete readiness checks
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.87] Docker container 0f4546652020 ready
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.88] Searching Docker registry credential in Auths
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.88] Searching Docker registry credential in CredHelpers
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.88] Searching Docker registry credential in Auths
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.88] Searching Docker registry credential in CredsStore
[testcontainers.org 00:00:03.88] Docker registry credential mcr.microsoft.com not found
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.66] Docker image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.66] Docker image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.66] Docker image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.69] Docker container cca5913864c9 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.69] Docker container dd669084423f created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.69] Start Docker container cca5913864c9
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.69] Start Docker container dd669084423f
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.70] Docker container 79e4da9ed893 created
[testcontainers.org 00:00:21.71] Start Docker container 79e4da9ed893
[testcontainers.org 00:00:22.12] Wait for Docker container 79e4da9ed893 to complete readiness checks
[testcontainers.org 00:00:22.15] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container 79e4da9ed893
[testcontainers.org 00:00:22.31] Wait for Docker container dd669084423f to complete readiness checks
[testcontainers.org 00:00:22.31] Wait for Docker container cca5913864c9 to complete readiness checks
[testcontainers.org 00:00:22.32] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container cca5913864c9
[testcontainers.org 00:00:22.32] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container dd669084423f
[testcontainers.org 00:00:31.17] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container 79e4da9ed893
[testcontainers.org 00:00:31.52] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container dd669084423f
[testcontainers.org 00:00:31.54] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container cca5913864c9
[testcontainers.org 00:00:32.42] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container 79e4da9ed893
[testcontainers.org 00:00:32.48] Docker container 79e4da9ed893 ready
Container /determined_bhabha 79e4da9ed89353a529a2631e133dea86cd50dfd1a53dbaabe83f40161c8f0ad7: Started
[testcontainers.org 00:00:32.78] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container cca5913864c9
[testcontainers.org 00:00:32.81] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container dd669084423f
[testcontainers.org 00:00:32.89] Docker container cca5913864c9 ready
Container /suspicious_wilbur  cca5913864c9ad5e961dcee21c6d38fde77e895e98749d97f73d8206cd520123: Started
[testcontainers.org 00:00:32.91] Docker container dd669084423f ready
Container /pensive_tu dd669084423f4f385568a04529bcbb982da98c461fe6083dc338e5c764f2df01: Started
[testcontainers.org 00:00:36.18] Delete Docker container cca5913864c9

I tried to debug but nothing is appearing there, changed my agent to several different version of ubuntu.
but still facing random fail.
Additional informations:
pipeline used:
# *********************************************************
# This pipeline builds and publishes the solution to the artifacts registry.
# It will run solely on the 'main' branch.
# *********************************************************
trigger:
  - develop
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  projectName: "Project.API"
  artifactName: "Project.API"
  buildConfiguration: "Release"

name: CI-Project-$(Build.BuildId)$(Rev:.r)

steps:
  - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
    displayName: "Nuget Authentication"

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Restore packages"
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: 'fced70aa-f1b3-4ab3-97a3-xxxxxx/3055a848-668b-4ec0-b933-xxxxxx'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Build solution"
    inputs:
      projects: "**/*.sln"
      arguments: "--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore"

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Run tests"
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: "**/*[tT]est**.csproj"
      arguments: "--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-build"
      publishTestResults: false

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Publish the app"
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: |
        **/*$(projectName).Functions.csproj

      arguments: "--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore"
      zipAfterPublish: false

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish Artifact: $(projectName)"
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      artifactName: "$(artifactName)"


Hi there, Welcome to SO. Can you let us know your pipeline definition like the YAML context to help understand your workflow to reproduce the issue? If your pipeline was running on a Microsoft-hosted agent, would you double check if the hardware could satisfy the requirement to build and test your project in containers?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT The same thing started happening to us today in a pipeline thats been working fine with testcontainers for a while.

Hi, the same thing started happening to our Azure pipelines too today. Any advancements in this?

nothing new on my side:
you can find below the spec for the agent used (Microsoft Hosted)
Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 20991.00 MB out of 74244.00 MB, Memory: Used 766.00 MB out of 6921.00 MB, CPU: Usage 55.55%
any thoughts ??

By randomly failing, was there any new commit added to the version of code that could succeed the build? Or the same version of code could succeed or fail randomly? What if you run some dummy tests in 3 containers, will the issue persist? Have tried to run the tests on a self-hosted agent with higher SKU for a test?
